# Reveal html text letter by letter smoothly on page scroll?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I need help trying to complete a JavaScript effect. I'm looking to accomplish the effect on this site https://www.lucidmotors.com/ - in the third section down on the home page you can see the text scroll/reveal is smooth over the other text.

I found this option on codepen https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/zYKoexK similar to the effect I need, but its a little to choppy I need it to be smoother.

**JS**

```
var textWrapper = document.querySelector(".ml3");
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
  /\S/g,
  "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
);

var letter = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");
var i = 0;
var currentID = 0;
var slideCount = letter.length;

document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  let scrolled =
    document.documentElement.scrollTop /
    (document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
      document.documentElement.clientHeight);

  //   var nextID = currentID + 1;

  //   if (nextID < slideCount) {
  //     letter[nextID].style.setProperty(
  //       "--percentage",
  //       `${scrolled / 1}` * nextID
  //     );
  //   }

  //   currentID = nextID;

  letter.forEach(function (l, i) {
    // console.log("====",i / letter.length, i, letter.length)
    if (i / letter.length < scrolled) {
      l.style.setProperty("--percentage", 1);
    } else {
      l.style.setProperty("--percentage", 0);
    }
  });
});
```

**CSS**

```
:root {
  --percentage: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  height: 600vh;
}

.ml3 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
}

.ml3 span {
  opacity: var(--percentage);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="ml3">
  <h1>THIS IS MY TEXT THAT IT'S GOING TO SHOW IN SCROLL</h1>
</div>
```

Any assistance would be great

Comment: I see you're interested only in vertical scroll, right?

Comment: You could move a transparent image over the text.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you're looking for, find it quite interesting and I think my answer can be improved, if you're interested only in the vertical scroll you should check the `window.scrollY` variable as well.

```js
var textWrapper = document.querySelector(".ml3");
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(
  /\S/g,
  "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"
);

var letter = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");

document.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
  let scrolled =
    document.documentElement.scrollTop /
    (document.documentElement.scrollHeight -
      document.documentElement.clientHeight) *
    letter.length;

  letter.forEach(function(l, i) {
    if ((scrolled - i) > 1)
      l.style.setProperty("--percentage", 1);
    else if ((scrolled - i) < 0.2)
      l.style.setProperty("--percentage", 0.2);
    else
      l.style.setProperty("--percentage", (scrolled - i));
  });
});
```

```css
:root {
  --percentage: 0.2;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  height: 600vh;
}

.ml3 {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

span {
  font-family: Helvetica;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 48px;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: -0.3px;
}

.ml3 span {
  opacity: var(--percentage);
}
```

```html
<div class="ml3">
  <h1>THIS IS MY TEXT THAT IT'S GOING TO SHOW IN SCROLL</h1>
</div>
```